# EF Core Text Search by Keywords

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I need to implement simple search by a list of keywords contains in a string. Assuming we have an entity:

```
public class Item
{
    public string A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
}
```

I need to have something like this:

```
var keywords = new [] {"one", "two", "three"};
_dbContext.Items.Where(i => keywords.All(k => (i.A + i.B).Contains(i)));
```

Is it possible to achieve with EF Core 2 and PostgreSQL?

Comment: You forgot to explain what does/doesn't work with the provided code

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto EF Core 2 npgsql cannot translate `All()` and `Contains()` statements into an appropriate SQL